# Styling HTML elements to fill 100% of parent width regarding min-width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want html elements to have width between 150px and 200px where they fill the 100% of parent width.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2 (after resizing window):

[image]

Image 3: (resizing a bit more):

[image]

Image 4: (even more):

[image]

I have tried `flexbox` but items are not filling the 100% of width:

(please check the sinppet in full screen)

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.flexitem {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important change is to allow `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` in combination with the min- and max-width. Now they are all between 150 and 200px wide. The last line doesn't fill the parent, which is not possible with these widths. Apart from that, i erased `display:flex` on the child elements - since they don't have children, this is of no use. I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to have the border included in your maximum of 200px:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background:#ff0000;
}

.flexitem {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width:150px;
  max-width:200px;
  background:#000000;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;   
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to add to your code is `flex: 1 1 150px` and all `flexitem`s will be between 150px and 200px.

*Note that it is obviously not possible to fill the last row to 100% parent width while wrapping if each `flexitem` is between 150px and 200px.*

**Why this works**:

1. The flex-shorthand `flex: 1 1 150px` means:

   a. `flex-grow` is allowed by setting it to 1

   b. `flex-shrink` is allowed by setting it to 1

   c. `flex-basis` is set to the `min-width` that is required
2. The `flex` setting along with `min-width` and `max-width` make the `flexitem`s go between 150px and 200px.

   *A word of caution though*: In rare cases there is some inconsistent behavior especially when using min and max values along with flex- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705876/css-scroll-issue-with-flexbox-and-max-height/39706325#39706325) for example.
3. Also added in `border-box` (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129811/add-border-to-div-increase-div-width/39130170#39130170)) and removed the `body` margin to finish it up.

Thanks!

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ff0000;
}
.flexitem {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="flexitem">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```